# Split vector of strings and paste subset of resulting elements into a new vector

Tags: r, string, vector, split

Define

```
z<- as.character(c("1_xx xx xxx_xxxx_12_sep.xls","2_xx xx xxx_xxxx_15_aug.xls"))
```

such that

```
> z
[1] "1_xx xx xxx_xxxx_12_sep.xls" "2_xx xx xxx_xxxx_15_aug.xls"
```

I want to create a vector *w* such that

```
> w
[1] "1_12_sep" "2_15_aug"
```

That is, split each element of *z* by *_* and then join elements 1,4,5, with the *.xls* removed from the latter.

I can manage the split part, but not sure what function to provide, e.g something like"

```
w <- as.character(lapply(strsplit(z,"_"), function(x) ???))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of `strsplit`, `substr` and `lapply`:

```
y <- strsplit(z,"_",fixed=TRUE)
lapply(y,FUN=function(x){paste(x[1],x[4],substr(x[5],1,3),sep="_")})
```

Comment: Many thanks!  I tried it and it works.  But I used `w <- as.vector(sapply(y,FUN=function(x){paste(x[1],x[4],substr(x[5],1,3),sep="_")}))` to get a vector instead of a list of lists.

Comment: @Fred, you could also use `sapply`, which makes the conversion, to vector in this case, by default. `as.vector` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Fred - No problem! But be sure to check out all the other (fairly slick) answers...

Comment: Having considered the various answers it would seem @Andrie's is the most sophisticated.  However, as a casual user of R, I find this answer to be the most legible.  I had to do a similar thing in Python and the code was very similar.  I guess I am just not very familiar with regular expressions and so find @Andrie's  code a little perplexing at first, whereas 'paste' and 'substr' are very familiar from other software. Hence why I vote this best.

Answer (score 8):

Using a bit of magic in the `stringr` package:  I separately extract the left and right date fields, combine them, and finally remove the `.xls` at the end.

```
library(stringr)
l <- str_extract(z, "\\d+_")
r <- str_extract(z, "\\d+_\\w*\\.xls")
gsub(".xls", "", paste(l, r, sep=""))

[1] "1_12_sep" "2_15_aug"
```

`str_extract` is a wrapper around some of the base R functions which I find easier to use.

**Edit** Here is a short explanation of what the regex does:

- `\\d+` looks for one or more digits.  It is escaped to distinguish from a normal character d.
- `\\w*` looks for zero or more alphanumeric characters (word).  Again, it's escaped.
- `\\.` looks for a decimal point.  This needs to be escaped because otherwise the decimal point means any single character.

In theory the regex should be quite flexible.  It should find single or double characters for your dates.

Answer (score 7):

One call to `gsub` (and some regex magic based on @Andrie's answer) can do this.  See `?regexp` for details on what I used in the `pattern` and `replacement` (back-reference) arguments.

```
gsub("^(\\d+_).*_(\\d+_\\w*).xls", "\\1\\2", z)
# [1] "1_12_sep" "2_15_aug"
```

Comment: +1 Nice.  I tried to do this initially, but gave up.  I forgot that you can back reference to more than one term.

Comment: @Andrie: I was wondering why you didn't go this route, since you're quite a regex guru.  You can have up to 9 back-references for extended regular expressions in R.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative along the same lines of @Joran's Answer is this:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    o <- paste(x[c(1,4,5)], collapse = "_")
    substr(o, 1, nchar(o) - 4) 
}

sapply(strsplit(z, "_"), foo)
```

The differences are minor - I use `collapse = "_"` and `nchar()` but other than that it is similar.

You can write this as a one-liner

```
sapply(strsplit(z, "_"), 
       function(x) {o <- paste(x[c(1,4,5)], 
                               collapse = "_"); substr(o, 1, nchar(o)-4)})
```

but writing the custom function to apply is nicer.