# Split elements of a string vector by pattern and add the split pieces as elements after the main part

Tags: regex, r, string, split

I have a large SPSS syntax file containing value labeling statements that I read in R vector. Each line starting with `/` contains variable name or names. The only exception is the first variable name (`one`) that does not start with `/`. The lines below them that do not start with `/` contain the values and their labels (the command "value labels"and the quotes around the labels that are mandatory in SPSS have been removed in advance).  The text in the file is structured, but has some inconsistencies: some of the values and their labels appear on the same line with the statements. Here is a small part of the vector after importing the text file:

```
> x <- c("one",
         "10 more",
         "20 less",
         "/two",
         "10 more",
         "20 less",
         "/three 10 more",
         "20 less",
         "30 enough",
         "/four to five",
         "10 more",
         "20 less",
         "/six 10 more 20 less",
         "/seven",
         "10 more",
         "20 less",
         "/eight 10 more 20 less",
         "30 enough",
         "/nine 10 more",
         "20 less",
         "/ten eleven 10 more",
         "20 less",
         "/twelve A some",
         "B none",
         "10 sufficient",
         "/thirteen",
         "A some",
         "B none",
         "10 sufficient")
```

As you can see, the fourth element, for example, is the statement `/two` and the next two elements are the values with their labels. However, there are some cases that differ, e.g. the seventh element (`/three 10 more`) which contains both the variable name and the first value with its label. The thirteenth element (`/six 10 more 20 less`) even contains all (two) values with their labels in the same element where the variable name is specified. In addition, there are elements that have more than one variable name specified and the first value with its label appears in the same element, e.g. the 21st (`/ten eleven 10 more`). Also, some elements containing ranges of variable names, e.g. the 10th (/four to five). Additional complication is that some of the values are characters, like in the 23rd element (`/twelve A some`) where even the value (`A`) and its label appear in the same element as the variable name.

What I want to achieve is to "move" these "misbehaving" pieces in new ones right after the string(s) starting with `/`, where they have been taken from. That is, to extract the values and their labels (like `10 more` from the seventh element - `/three 10 more`) from the elements starting with `/`, keeping the variable labels (single, multiple or ranges) and put them as new elements right after the original elements where they were extracted from. Same for the elements that start with `/` and a variable name, followed by character value and its label. Said another way, from the elements starting with `/` and variable name(s) all parts that that start with number or a capital letter followed by a lowercase word should be extracted and put in a new string right after the trimmed original where they have been extracted from.

That is, to manipulate the vector in a way that will give the following output vector:

```
> x
 [1] "one"                   
 [2] "10 more"               
 [3] "20 less"               
 [4] "/two"                  
 [5] "10 more"               
 [6] "20 less"
 [7] "/three"
 [8] "10 more"        
 [9] "20 less"               
[10] "30 enough"             
[11] "/four to five"         
[12] "10 more"               
[13] "20 less"               
[14] "/six"
[15] "10 more"
[16] "20 less"  
[17] "/seven"                
[18] "10 more"               
[19] "20 less"               
[20] "/eight"
[21] "10 more
[22] "20 less"
[23] "30 enough"             
[24] "/nine"
[25] "10 more"      
[26] "20 less"               
[27] "/ten eleven"
[28] "10 more"
[29] "20 less"               
[30] "/twelve"
[31] "A some"         
[32] "B none"                
[33] "10 sufficient"         
[34] "/thirteen"             
[35] "A some"                
[36] "B none"                
[37] "10 sufficient"
```

Thank you for your help.

**Still [on hold]**

After the post was put on hold yesterday, I edited the entire posting. I hope now it is clearer. Can you please revise and free it or let me know if it is still not fine, advising what exactly to change. Thank you.

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: You havne't provided a very specific matching rule. Things like `"/four to five"` and `"/twelve A some"` are going to look pretty much the same to the computer. What would determine which of those are split and which are not.

Comment: @MrFlick: You are absolutely right. But actually this is part of the problem I have... I would even say is the bigger part of it...

Comment: @user227710: I tried modifying the suggestions from the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391989/split-vector-of-strings-and-paste-subset-of-resulting-elements-into-a-new-vector) but without any success.

Comment: If you can't work out some criteria for which strings to split and which not to, it's very hard for us to help you.

Comment: MrFlick hit the nail on the head about needing clear rules for `"/four to five" and "/twelve A some"`

Comment: What about this: "if it's '/{word} {capital letter or digits}' then split, otherwise preserve" - this works on your example data, but is it a reasonable rule for your actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given a clear criteria for when to split and when not, but from your example data it looks like if you always separate out strings that look like '{capital letter} {lowercase word}' or '{digits} {lowercase word}' and otherwise leave as-is.

Here's something that achieves that, though as mentioned, I'm trying to mind-read here.

```
out <- unlist(lapply(x,
              function (str) {
                  strsplit(str, ' (?=[A-Z0-9]+ [a-z]+\\b)', perl=T)
              }))
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying for a while, I was trying to figure out how to define the rules more clear and tried to do it based on the suggestion in your previous comment. The suggestion you provide here works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I am quite new to R (and programming) and still confused by the regular expressions, especially Perl ones. Thank you once again for the solution!

Comment: When you're formulating a question, forget the regex for a moment and decide on a rule you can express in plain language (e.g. "extract all strings that start with a capital letter or number followed by a lowercase word, and leave the rest") - we can take care of converting that to regex.